# Is there a way to list down only the custom dotnet templates installed?

Tags: c#, .net-core, command-line-interface

`dotnet new --list` lists all the built-in and custom templates installed. But I want to list only the custom templates that I have created and installed. Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have author specified in you template for example:

```json
{
  "$schema": "http://json.schemastore.org/template",
  "author": "MyCompany",
  "classifications": [ "Item" ],
  "identity": "MyCompany.Templates.Documentation",
  "name": "Documentation template",
  "shortName": "documentation",
  "preferNameDirectory": false,
  "tags": {
    "type": "item"
  }
}
```

then you can filter it by that company name: `dotnet new --list --author MyCompany`.

I'm aware that this solution is very limited but at least works when I want to list only my templates.

NOTE: the syntax is valid for .NET SDK 6.0.100. For (currently in preview) version .NET SDK 7.0.100 it is `dotnet new list --author MyCompany`